# create a new column with three conditions using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

how can I get three conditions in np.where(). normally it uses only two conditions how can I get three.
Like I need to Create a new column Better_Event that stores 'Summer' ,'Winter' or 'Both' based on the comparision between the total medals won in Summer event and Winter event (i.e. comparision between the Total_Summer and Total_Winter columns) using "np.where()"function.

```
data['Better_Events'] = np.where(data['Total_Summer']>data['Total_Winter'],'Summer','Winter')
```

the above code only has two output . how do I change it to three where if 
data['Total_Summer']==data['Total_Winter'] gives "Both"

Comment: you need numpy.select

Comment: show an example of your dataframe please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

**Here is an example:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Total_Summer':[1,2,3,3,6,7],'Total_Winter':[2,2,3,4,5,4]})
print(df)
```

---

```
   Total_Summer  Total_Winter
0             1             2
1             2             2
2             3             3
3             3             4
4             6             5
5             7             4
```

---

**now set the conditions and value for each condition:**

```
cond=[df['Total_Summer']>df['Total_Winter'],df['Total_Summer']<df['Total_Winter'],df['Total_Summer'].eq(df['Total_Winter'])]
values=['Summer','Winter','Both']
df['Better_Events']=np.select(cond,values)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Total_Summer  Total_Winter Better_Events
0             1             2        Winter
1             2             2          Both
2             3             3          Both
3             3             4        Winter
4             6             5        Summer
5             7             4        Summer
```

Comment: thanku but I need to use np.where() for the given problem statement

Comment: why doy you need np.where?

Comment: Everything you can do with np.where can be done with np.select. The opposite is not true

Comment: its an assignment :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'apply' with axis=1:

```
Total_Summer  Total_Winter
0            74            17
1            75            29
2            48            64
3            77            77
4            16            38

df.apply(lambda r: "Both" if r.Total_Summer==r.Total_Winter else "Summer" if r.Total_Summer>r.Total_Winter else "Winter" ,axis=1) 

Out: 
0    Summer
1    Summer
2    Winter
3      Both
4    Winter
dtype: object
```

Or you can use np.where twice:

```
np.where( df.Total_Summer.eq(df.Total_Winter),"Both", np.where(df.Total_Summer.gt(df.Total_Winter),"Summer","Winter"))
```

The second method is faster.

Comment: to avoid having to do something as cumbersome as this exists np.select..

Comment: @ansev You're right. It' s just a presentation of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy.select works great, however I do want to present an alternate solution which should be better when the conditions are more numerous or complex:

```
# numpy is only used to create the test data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

total_summer, total_winter = np.split(np.random.randint(low=0, high=15, size=20), 2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(total_summer, total_winter), columns=["total_summer", "total_winter"])

def find_better_event(row):
    res : str
    if row["total_summer"] > row["total_winter"]:
        res = "Summer"
    elif row["total_summer"] < row["total_winter"]:
        res = "Winter"
    else:
        res = "Both"
    return res

df["better_events"] = df.apply(find_better_event, axis=1)
```