# How to update a row on the basis of keywords from another row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to update one column which is "maincategory" on the basis of words in "name" column i.e: if name name columns contains pharma update pharmaceutical in "maincategory" column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnNgg.png)

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: how to post csv data here ?@ansev

Comment: read your csv with df=pd.read_csv('your csv') and then use print(df) and copy  and paste the output

Comment: df['maincategory'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x : 'pharmaceutical' if 'pharma' in x else 'not pharma')

Comment: please replace your image with code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thanks alot @vb_rises this is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) + [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["maincategory"]=np.where(df['name'].str.contains('pharma'),'pharma','not pharma')
```

**Here is an example:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['(pharma)abdc','a12dff','pharma 1234']})
print(df)

           name
0  (pharma)abdc
1        a12dff
2   pharma 1234
```

---

```
df["maincategory"]=np.where(df['name'].str.contains('pharma'),'pharma','not pharma')
print(df)

           name maincategory
0  (pharma)abdc       pharma
1        a12dff   not pharma
2   pharma 1234       pharma
```

Comment: what if i want to apply this on all rows else case would not work in that?

Comment: I recommend you also see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html

Comment: I mean to say i have so many other different rows other than pharma what to do in that case?@ansev

Comment: then you need np.select: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

Comment: I am glad to help you!, here is an example of np.select: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58308972/create-a-new-column-with-three-conditions-using-np-where

Comment: Thank you so much man figuring out how do it in my case?@ansev